# No known instance method for selector 'valueForKey:' for id <NSObject, NSCoding> object

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, key-value-coding

I'm getting an error I can't shake. When I try to access an `id <NSObject, NSCoding>`'s property with `valueForKey` the code is fine for the function parameter, `item`, but is not for a similar `id` I retrieve out of an array. Why is this?

```
- (void) insertItem:(id<NSCoding, NSObject >) item {
            for (int i = 0; i < [self.sortDescriptors count]; i++) {
                NSString  *propertyString = self.sortDescriptors[i].key;
                int idx = 0;
                id<NSCoding, NSObject > comparisonItem = self.items[idx];
                while ([[item valueForKey: propertyString] compare:[comparisonItem valueForKey: propertyString]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                     ....
```

It's this call:

```
[comparisonItem valueForKey: propertyString]
```

That is producing this error:

```
No known instance method for selector 'valueForKey:'
```

**What am I  missing and how can I do the comparison for a dynamically named property?**

Comment: What is the actual data type of the object pointed to by `item` when you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `id<NSCoding, NSObject >`, type this value as an `NSObject*`.

Comment: you are absolutely right. So does that mean the NSObject protocol is not the same as inheriting from NSObject? It's a subset of the selectors?

Comment: `valueForKey:` is not part of the NSObject protocol. It is part of the NSObject class.

Comment: @sunny `NSObject` is the standard ObjC base class. Implementing the `NSObject` protocol lets your custom base class act like `NSObject`.

Comment: See my essay, The Secret Life of NSObject http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#SECSecretLife